# AddThis Sharing Bar Not Displaying on Custom Page Template - JS conflict?

Tags: javascript

http://www.headcount.org/a-real-whodunnit-the-oil-spill-blame-game/ - on the single posts the sharing bar displays.

http://www.headcount.org/blog/ - on the blog archive page it doesn't (even after choosing archive, category, index as options within the AddThis option, though I have not chosen excerpts at this point because that's not what we want).

This page uses the_content, not get_the_content, and when I view the source, I can SEE the bar in the source below the post meta, but it's just not displaying. Any thoughts as to why it's not showing on this particular page? I've deactivated all the plugins and that didn't fix it.

AddThis support suggests that it's then an issue with the JS in the theme itself, but javascript isn't in my strong skill set - I need help sorting that out. I've just started working with this client so I'm still learning my way around their installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two functions operate differently. get_the_content retrieves the raw data from the database, where the_content retrieves the data, encapsulates areas with paragraph tags, cleans up, and applies filters.

I'm confused which is using which, but if the page that is missing the AddThis is using the get_the_content, try applying the filters from the plugins before displaying it:

```
<?php apply_filters('the_content',get_the_content( $more_link_text, $stripteaser, $more_file )) ?>
```

Make sure to use the same arguments as the original get_the_content function call. Strip out any that you aren't using, so the minimum would be:

```
<?php apply_filters('the_content',get_the_content()) ?>
```

I should add that the Javascript that you saw on the /blog/ page was not for individual AddThis instances, so it isn't a JS conflict.